# this JavaScript log in wont work

Tags: javascript

i found and edited this code from this website for practice but the code wont work with me. the goal of the code is to create a username and password on one page (which for now is limited to premade usernames and passwords) and send that array of information to another page where you can log in using the username and password from the other page. the code looks fine to me but i am an amateur and want to know what is wrong with it. thank you for your answer.

the code for where the username and password are defined is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>
create account
</title>


<script>
sessionStorage.setItem("unArray", JSON.stringify("bob", "sam"));
sessionStorage.setItem("pwArray", JSON.stringify("lol", "jk"));
</script>


</head>

<body>

</body>


</html>
```

the code for taking the already created username and password from the above page and using that for a log in page is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
log on page
</title>

<script type = "text/javascript">
var count = 2;

function validate() {
    var un = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var pw = document.getElementById("pword").value
    var valid = false;

    var unArray = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("unArray"));
    var pwArray = JSON.parse(vsessionStorage.getItem("pwArray"));

    for (var i=0; i <unArray.length; i++) {
        if ((un == unArray[i]) && (pw == pwArray[i])) {
        valid = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (valid) {
        alert ("Login was successful");
        window.location = "http://www.google.com";
        return false;
    }

    var t = " tries";

    if (count == 1) {t = " try"}

    if (count >= 1) {
        alert ("Invalid username and/or password. " +
               "You have " + count + t + " left.");
        document.myform.username.value = "";
        document.myform.pword.value = "";
        setTimeout("document.myform.username.focus()", 25);
        setTimeout("document.myform.username.select()", 25);
        count --;
    }

    else {
        alert ("Still incorrect! You have no more tries left!");
        document.myform.username.value = "No more tries allowed!";
        document.myform.pword.value = "";
        document.myform.username.disabled = true;
        document.myform.pword.disabled = true;
        return false;
    }

}
</script>

    <style>

    p.log_on{
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    left: 20px;
}
</style>





</head>


<body>


<form name = "myform">
  <p class="log_on">
    ENTER USER NAME <input type="text" id="username"><br><br><br><br><br>
    ENTER PASSWORD <input type="password" id="pword">
    <input type="button" value="Check In" id="Submit" onclick="validate()">
  </p>
</form>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: `sessionStorage.setItem("unArray", JSON.stringify( ["bob", "sam"] ));`

Comment: i made the change but it did not help. the error that popped up is Uncaught ReferenceError: vsessionStorage is not defined

Comment: So correct that typo in the second script ... The error tells you **exactly** what's wrong

Comment: can someone show me the code for that. i must remind you i am new to JavaScript.

Comment: At one point you typed `vsessionStorage` instead of `sessionStorage`. Just correct that.

Comment: my code still wont give you any output when you hit the button. all it lets you do is type in the text boxes.

Answer (score 2):

The following two lines:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("unArray", JSON.stringify("bob", "sam"));
sessionStorage.setItem("pwArray", JSON.stringify("lol", "jk"));
```

are not using the `JSON.stringify` function correctly.

They should be:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("unArray", JSON.stringify(["bob", "sam"]));
sessionStorage.setItem("pwArray", JSON.stringify(["lol", "jk"]));
```

See the following link for reference: [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Per the documentation, the `JSON.stringify` parameters are defined as the following:

> ### Syntax
>
> `JSON.stringify(value[, replacer [, space]])`
>
> ### Parameters
>
> `value` - The value to convert to a JSON string.
>
> `replacer` (Optional) - If a function, transforms values and properties encountered while stringifying; if an array, specifies the set of properties included in objects in the final string.
>   A detailed description of the replacer function is provided in the JavaScript guide article Using native JSON.
>
> `space` (Optional) - Causes the resulting string to be pretty-printed.